# скрипт перевода числа из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, что в скрипте

```
<php
$bin = $_POST['Двоичное_число'];
function myBin2Dec($bin)
{
  $result_dbg = "";
  $result = 0;
  $dataLen = strlen($bin);

  for($i = 0, $sh = $dataLen; $i < $dataLen; $i++, $sh--){
    $elem = (int) substr($bin, $sh - 1, 1);
    $result_dbg .= "$elem*(2^$i) +"; 
    $result += $elem * pow(2, $i);
  }

  echo "=======\n<br>result = ".$result."; base = 10\n</br>=======</br>";
  $result_dbg .=" = $result";
  echo (  $result_dbg );
   return $result;
}

myBin2Dec ($bin);
?>
```

обозначает sh--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом скрипте и во всех остальных это означает [декремент](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: понятно, спасибо